# How to assign a derived type list to base type list in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

How to achieve `List<Employee> e = new List<Associate>()`? Is this wrong?

```
class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Associate : Employee
{
}

class Compute
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Employee> e = new List<Associate>();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have another class that inherits from `Employee` as well, say,

```
class Manager : Employee
{
}
```

Then, in your example this could happen,

```
class Compute
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Associate>();
        employees.Add(new Manager()); // Hmmm... what?
    }
}
```

And suddenly you have a `Manager` in a list of `Associate`, which violate the type rules because `Manager` and `Associate` have no class relationship. That's part of the reason why `List<T>` has the declared the `T` type parameter as *invariant* (rather than `List<out T>` or covariant, where something like this could actually happen).

Answer (score 3):

You can add derived classes to lists of base classes.

```
List<Employee> e= new List<Employee>();
e.Add(new Associate());
```

Comment: Thank you Drankin, helps me much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not. The reason of this behavior is that you still will be able to add base class instances to a list what should be just derived classes (as covered in [blogs.msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) provided by BrunoLM).

```
e.Add(new Employee());
```

Following are possible ways to avoid the problem:

- you can have list of base class items as you can easily add instances of derived class.
- you can use `var` in code to implicitly define type of variable (it indeed will be of type `List<Associate>`
- if you need to pass this list to a function - make argument [`IEnumerable<Employee>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and you'll be able to pass either `List<Employee>` or `List<Associate>`)
- you can use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter elements of derived classes from list of elements of base class.